# Can't find Query Analyzer

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I use SQL Server Mgt. Studio via SQL Server 2008 R 2 at work.  Trying to rid all triggers in my test database but I couldn't copy the results to run them in Query Analyzer, because I can't find it.  Can someone please give me some advice?

Comment: As of SQL Server **2005**, you get the **Management Studio** as the GUI to use, which does all that Enterprise Manager **and** Query Analyzer ever did...

Answer (score 0):

Go to Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 -> SQL Server Management Studio for Query Analyzer.